# Mysql self join instead of group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Mysql table Waypoint, where all waypoints of a trip are saved:

```
ID,TripID,Location
1 ,5     ,Barcelona
2 ,5     ,Madrid
3 ,5     ,Valencia
4 ,6     ,Berlin
5 ,6     ,Hamburg
6 ,6     ,Munich
```

Now I want to get all possible direct flights to cover the whole trip

TripID,Departure,Destination

```
5,Barcelona,Madrid
5,Barcelona,Valencia
5,Madrid,Valencia
6,Berlin,Hamburg
6,Berlin,Munich
6,Hamburg,Munich
```

I have tried it with group_concat but that didn't help

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you have a graph problem, and MySQL is not well-equiped to solve these.  The missing piece of functionality is recursive queries.

In your case, though, I think you can do what you want with a self-join:

```
select wp1.tripid, wp1.location, wp2.location
from Waypoint wp1 join
     Waypoint wp2
     on wp1.tripid = wp2.tripid and wp1.id < wp2.id;
```

Note the `<` condition.  It filters out duplicates of the form "Madrid, Barcelona".